# Please explain the following step

Tags: probability

From this P(|XnYn|>e,|yn|>e/k) how I am getting the next step i.e. P(|Yn|>e/k) and how the LHS is becoming less than the RHS
[image]

Answer (score 2):

$P(A \cap B) \le P(A)$ because $A \cap B$ is a subset of $A$. That’s for the part that is underlined. For the other part of that line it’s the same idea. The probability of a subset is always smaller than or equal to the probability of the superset.

There are some hints, too, for problems like these. If, in the statement of a theorem, there’s no mention of any other tools, all you have to use is a definition and some axioms.

Comment: Thank you very much....